# JDBC Driver is found when doing UT, but not when the jar is compiled

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle, amazon-redshift

I was trying to set up a JDBC connection to a redshift database in my java code and created a few UTs that would make calls to that database using the driver.

The problem lies (probably) in my Gradle as a classpath problem, as the UTs runs fine, but when I'm deploying the jar on my server, suddenly I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Here is my function :

```
private void establishJDBCConnection() throws Exception {
    Class.forName("com.amazon.redshift.jdbc42.Driver");
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("user", USERNAME);
    props.setProperty("password", PWD);
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, props);
}
```

And here is my gradle files (I've tried reducing them, but I don't know much about which parts are important so it may still be a bit big)
We are running with gradle 5.2.1

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'osgi'
apply plugin: 'partnerextension'

group = 'com.stuff'
// Setup of version, dependencies, imports, names...
version = '3.9.0.14'

// Repositories for the script itself (STIBO Added)
buildscript {
    repositories{

        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
            maven {
                url "https://artifactory-2018.schneider-electric.com/artifactory/oneoffer-oim-libs-step9.3"
            }
            maven {
                url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-maven-repository/release"
            }
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.stibo:com.stibo.gradle.plugin.partnerextension:1.0.0'
        }
    }
}

// Repositories for the project
repositories {
    mavenCentral() 
    maven {
        url "https://artifactory-2018.schneider-electric.com/artifactory/oneoffer-oim-libs-step9.3"
    }
    maven {
        url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/redshift-maven-repository/release"
    }
}
jar {
    baseName = "com.stuff-${version}"
    manifest {
        // Do not export anything from the bundle
        instruction 'Export-Package', "!*"
    }
}
apply from :'partner.gradle'
```

partner.gradle:

```
// Setup of version, dependencies, imports, names...
def artifactName
// added so to declare external component POI
configurations {
    includeInJar
}

dependencies {
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    testCompile "org.mockito:mockito-core:2.18.3" 

    //compile group: 'com.amazon.redshift', name: 'redshift-jdbc42', version: '1.2.43.1067'

    compile group: 'com.amazon.redshift', name: 'redshift-jdbc42-no-awssdk', version: '1.2.8.1005'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-redshift', version: '1.11.920'
    
    // added to declare POI
    includeInJar 'some jars', \/* , \
            'com.amazon.redshift:redshift-jdbc42:1.2.43.1067'*/
    configurations.compile.extendsFrom(configurations.includeInJar)
}

jar {
    into('lib') {
        println "includeInJar: " + configurations.includeInJar.collect { File file -> file }
        from configurations.includeInJar
    }

    // generate checksum
    def folder = new File( "${buildDir}")
    if( !folder.exists() ) {
    // Create all folders up-to and including B
    folder.mkdirs()
    }

    manifest {
        def jarName = "com.stuff"
                
        instruction 'Bundle-ClassPath', \
                'somejars'/*, \
                'lib/redshift-jdbc42-1.2.43.1067.jar' */

        instruction 'Import-Package',
            '''someimports'''
        
        archiveName = "${jarName}-${version}.jar"
        artifactName = archiveName                                        
    }
}
```

I've tried adding the redshift driver jar to my generated jar, but that does not make the class available. I've tried adding a main that would run this function and use the -cp to add the driver-jar to my classpath, but it didn't work either.

I've tried using the PostgreSQL driver instead of redshift, didn't work.
Also, can anyone explain to me how can the code work fine during UT? it makes no sense to me!

Comment: Under what directory within your jar did you add the jar to your jar?

Comment: they are under the lib directory, which is itself is in the root of the jar (aside of the META-INF directory if that helps)

Comment: Are you creating an OSGI bundle? If no, you are probably getting your jar layouts mixed up. You can't include other jars in a jar without a special class loader, and you don't mention that either. So what is your goal for the final deployable artifact (how should you run it)?

Comment: I believe i'm making a osgi bundle (but as i said i'm not proficient in gradle), for exmaple i have the Bundle-ClassPath in the manifest that, from my researchs, show that it's for osgi bundles. the jar is then packaged and installed on a tool we use as a component for use. this is how every other components we have are made.